How to Center the Middle Child Element in a Flexbox Parent with Uneven Widths?
I have a parent container with display: flex and justify-content: space-between. Inside this parent, I have three child elements with uneven widths. Here's a simplified version of my HTML and CSS:
I am using tailwind just for clearance
<div class="flex justify-between">
  <div class="w-24">Child 1</div>
  <div class="w-28">Child 2</div>
  <div class="w-20">Child 3</div>
</div>

the second child element is not centered within the parent container because of the uneven widths of the child elements.
I want the second child to be exactly in the center of the parent div, while still maintaining the space-between alignment for the other two children without using 'Absolute' Position
i have tried google but didn't got any expected results

a grid layout would probably do better here : example https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/abrgKqZ

You could consider using a margin offset with the difference in width like:


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.4"></script>

<div class="flex justify-between">
  <div class="w-24">Child 1</div>
  <div class="w-28">Child 2</div>
  <!-- Using calc() to be more expressive and in case of any configuration changes. -->
  <div class="w-20 ml-[calc(theme(width.24)-theme(width.20))]">Child 3</div>
</div>

<div class="flex justify-between">
  <div class="w-24">Child 1</div>
  <div class="w-28">Child 2</div>
  <!-- Otherwise, you could use `4` -->
  <div class="w-20 ml-4">Child 3</div>
</div>



Or you could consider using a grid layout, with equal-width left and right column grid track sizings:


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.4"></script>

<div class="grid grid-cols-[1fr_auto_1fr]">
  <div class="w-24">Child 1</div>
  <div class="w-28">Child 2</div>
  <div class="w-20 justify-self-end">Child 3</div>
</div>




i found the grid approach as you showed to be the best solution
